# Dividing certain members of a list in python

Tags: python, list, range

I have a matrix formed by a list of lists and I want to divide each member of the second half of each sublist by the integer in the first 3 members of each sublist. Here is my code:

```
def matrix():

    a=[[12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12, 156, -108], [0.0, 2.667, 0.0, -5.333, -77.333, 53.333], [0.0, 0.0, -0.0937, -0.0937, -1.4687, 1.0]]

    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = [v/a[i][i] for v in a[i]]

    return a
```

However, this code divides each entire sublist by the integer found in the first half of each sublist which gives me this output:

```
[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 13.0, -9.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.9996250468691417, -28.996250468691414, 19.99737532808399], [-0.0, -0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 15.674493062966913, -10.672358591248665]]
```

I only want the second part of each sublist divided, not the first half. I need to obtain this output, as you can see the first 3 integers of each sublist must stay the same:

```
[[12,0,0,1,13,-9],[0,2.667,0,-2,-29,20],[0,0,-0.09375,1,15.6667,-10.6667]]
```

Comment: What does "divide ... by the integer in the first 3 members of each sublist" mean? The first 3 members of the 1st sublist are `12.0, 0.0, 0.0` for example. Do you mean "divide by the 1st item in the sublist"?

Comment: @jarmod yes exactly, for the first sublist it would be 12 but in the second sublist it's the second member which is 2.667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split up your logic into two steps:

1. Find the integer in the first three numbers.
2. Divide the second half of each sublist by that number.

   ```
   def matrix():
       a = [[12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12, 156, -108],
            [0.0, 2.667, 0.0, -5.333, -77.333, 53.333],
            [0.0, 0.0, -0.0937, -0.0937, -1.4687, 1.0]]

       for i in range(len(a)):
           divisor = 0
           for j in range(3):
               if a[i][j]:
                   divisor = a[i][j]
                   break
           for j in range(len(a[i]) // 2, len(a[i])):
               a[i][j] = a[i][j] / divisor

       return a


   print(matrix())
   ```

**Output:**

```
[[12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 13.0, -9.0], [0.0, 2.667, 0.0, -1.9996250468691417, -28.996250468691414, 19.99737532808399], [0.0, 0.0, -0.0937, 1.0, 15.674493062966913, -10.672358591248665]]
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without importing round? @ShashSinha

Comment: if you don't import round you will get long numbers because of floating-point precision: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: the long float numbers are okay, I just can't import round, how can I take it out of the code?

Comment: Hope that is satisfactory :)